# Convert the Worksheet_Change event to code that runs on demand

Tags: excel, vba, events

I would like to convert the Worksheet_Change event into code that runs on demand.

The below code runs when the user make changes in the worksheet.

I want it to execute on demand.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim CPTCode, EmpName As Range
    Dim Cnt As Double
    Set CPTCode = Range("J5:J400")  ''' This is the Product Code range
    Set EmpName = Range("D5")  ''' This is the Emp Name focus

    If Not Intersect(Target, CPTCode) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Value = " " Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
        Cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CPTCode, Target)

        If Cnt = 4 Then
            MsgBox EmpName & "You have sold " & Cnt & " Product" _
              & vbNewLine & "and If you sold one more time this Product, you will get an increment.", vbInformation, "SALES RULES"
        ElseIf Cnt = 5 Then
            MsgBox EmpName & ", CONGRATULATIONS!  you got an increment.", vbExclamation, "SALES RULES"
        ElseIf Cnt > 5 Then
            MsgBox EmpName & ", You cannot sale more than 5 times this product.", vbCritical, "SALES RULES"
            Target.ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new module: Insert -> Module
Paste this code into the new module:

```
Sub YourMacroName()
    Dim CPTCode As Range, EmpName As Range
    Dim Cnt As Double
    Dim Target As Range
    Set CPTCode = Range("J5:J400")  ''' This is the Product Code range
    Set EmpName = Range("D5")  ''' This is the Emp Name focus
    Set Target = ActiveCell

    If Not Intersect(Target, CPTCode) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Value = " " Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
        Cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CPTCode, Target)

        If Cnt = 4 Then
            MsgBox EmpName & "You have sold " & Cnt & " Product" _
            & vbNewLine & "and If you sold one more time this Product, you will get an increment.", vbInformation, "SALES RULES"
        ElseIf Cnt = 5 Then
            MsgBox EmpName & ", CONGRATULATIONS!  you got an increment.", vbExclamation, "SALES RULES"
        ElseIf Cnt > 5 Then
            MsgBox EmpName & ", You cannot sale more than 5 times this product.", vbCritical, "SALES RULES"
            Target.ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I made `Target` to refer to the `ActiveCell`.